# How to install Rails when dealing with "Load Error with Gems"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to get Ruby on Rails working on my laptop and haven't been able to. At some point I took some bad advice and used `sudo` and have been trying to undo that error and the corresponding issues since.

As of right now, `ruby -v` shows

```sh
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

So, I think Ruby is installed. When I try to run `gem install rails` or any other gem command like `gem install bundler`, I get this error

```sh
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/audreybrooke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- executable-hooks/wrapper (LoadError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/audreybrooke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gem-wrappers-1.4.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- gem-wrappers (LoadError)
/Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/yaml.rb:3: warning: It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    20: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
    19: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:44:in `run'
    18: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `do_configuration'
    17: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `new'
    16: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:182:in `initialize'
    15: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:332:in `load_file'
    14: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:710:in `load_yaml'
    13: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    12: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    11: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/yaml.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     9: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     8: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     6: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     5: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/nodes.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     3: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     2: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/audreybrooke/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/audreybrooke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/stringio-0.1.0/lib/stringio.bundle (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have not installed `libyaml` correctly. Since you are using MacOS, maybe install it using `homebrew` can solve the problem.

```
brew install libyaml && brew link libyaml
```

I recommending to use [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/). It handle these like of dependency problems under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I did

> sudo rm -rf ~/.rvm

because I had rvm and rbenv installed and that worked